# How to access redux store in routeConfig (react-navigation)

Tags: react-native, redux, react-navigation

here's the code example:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state: RootState) => ({
  isSwipeEnabled: state.permissions.isSwipeEnabled,
});

const MainNavigator = createMaterialTopTabNavigator(
  {
    Screen1,
    Screen2: {
      screen: Screen2,
      navigationOptions: {
        swipeEnabled: isSwipeEnabled, <==HERE I WANT TO USE MY REDUX STATE
      },
    },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Screen1',
    tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
  },
);

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MainNavigator);
```

Is it possible to have access to redux inside createMaterialTopTabNavigator function? 
If it is, how?

Thanks!

Comment: What is access to Redux? To the store? actions?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your navigator in constructor of App component, which is connected to redux. In constructor you can access your mapped state from props:

```js
const mapStateToProps = (state: RootState) => ({
    isSwipeEnabled: state.permissions.isSwipeEnabled
});

class NavigationApp extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.mainNavigator = createMaterialTopTabNavigator(
            {
                Screen1,
                Screen2: {
                    screen: Screen2,
                    navigationOptions: {
                        // here you now can use your mapped redux state from props
                        swipeEnabled: props.isSwipeEnabled, 
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                initialRouteName: 'Screen1',
                tabBarPosition: 'bottom'
            },
        );
    }

    render() {
        // use here any function from react-navigation which you are using in your environment
        // e.g. createAppContainer
        // in this example I am using createBrowserApp for using react-navigation in web app
        const App = createBrowserApp(this.mainNavigator);
        return (<App />);
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(NavigationApp);
```